# How do I continue the execution when exec(sleep NUMBER; anotherCommand) in PHP?

Tags: php, html, linux

I have this code:

```
<?php
    exec("sleep 15m; ls -l");
    echo "Done";
?>
```

But it gets stuck and won't stop loading until 15 minutes have passed, is there anyway to not wait for the exec execution?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you’re actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PHP - exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

> **exec**
>   ...
>   **Note**:
>
> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

So you must redirect the output *and* start it in the background

```
exec("(sleep 15m; ls -l) >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to execute your command in the background:

```
exec("(sleep 15m ; ls -l) &")
```

Comment: redirect the output to a file or /dev/null too.

Comment: The problem remains the same, "Done" is not printed until 15 min has elapsed.